# Flot: Consistent label colors throughout screen with multiple stacked bar charts

Tags: javascript, jquery, flot

Here's my [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/6bh9396v/)

I need the dynamic labels to have the same color if the same label is found in another chart, and if possible to have the same order in the stack bar, throughout all charts.
 e.g if you look at the color purple it has 3 labels against it: 084, 080, 00. It should be only 084/080/00 against purple. These should reflect throughout all charts within a screen.

```
$.plot($("#placeholder"), chartData, chartOptions);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build a list of labels and used colors by looping through your `chartData` arrays, see this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6bh9396v/1/) for a working example:

```
var colors = {
    _count: 1
};
function distributeColors(data) {
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        var label = data[i].label;
        if (!colors[label]) {
            colors[label] = colors._count++;
        }
        data[i].color = colors[label];
    }
}
distributeColors(chartData);
distributeColors(chartData2);
distributeColors(chartData3);
```

Comment: any way of ordering the stacking of the bars labels to be consistent throughout all charts?

Comment: That should rather be a new and separate question. But in principal you could loop through your data sets and build a newly ordered version of each.

Comment: I'll post this new question in a minute in a new post

Comment: Maybe try to code it yourself first and then come back later ;-)

Comment: I think I've done it. Can I have your opinion? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34136537/flot-order-the-stacking-of-the-bars-throughout-screen-with-multiple-stacked-bar  jsfiddle line 188

Comment: I don't see a question there, but it looks like it's working fine. If your charts always include all labels, you don't need to change / set the colors. (You need to do it, if there can be gaps.)

Comment: edited the post. In a closer inspection of the results I see that the stacked bars does not have the same order throughout all charts