# Flot: Order the stacking of the bars throughout screen with multiple stacked bar charts

Tags: javascript, flot

Se the [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/gxxjhqvf/)

**Q:** I need to order the stacked bars so it'll be consistent throughout a screen with multiple stacked bar charts. 
 e.g if one bar has stacked labels starting with the top to bottom 087, 084, 080, 01-02, 00 then the position should be the same in all the other charts

I've tried:

```
chartData.sort(function(a, b){ 
    return a.label.localeCompare(b.label);
});
```

But it does not seem to work for stacked labels in one bar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a problem with the stacking when one data series in the chart has a gap at a specific x value. For example the middle bar (at x = 2) in chart 2:

```
{
    label: "084",
    data: [
        [0, 3],
        [1, 12],
        [2, 0], // this was missing, after adding it, the stacking works
        [3, 53],
        [4, 13]
    ]
}
```